# Connecting existing Amazon Database with Bluemix

Tags: php, sql, database, amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud

I have more of a generic question here, I was wondering if it was possible to connect an existing Amazon Database to the IBM Bluemix service using a PHP buildpack? I cannot really find anything specific about this. 
Could someone perhaps point me to the right resource on how to do this in the right manner?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing preventing your application from connecting to any publicly accessible database endpoint. Connect to its IP address as you normally would.

Take a look at [this blog](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/14/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/) for best practices on how to share the db credentials with your Bluemix app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

You can connect to any service out there that you can connect to on the public Internet.

What you could do is store your connection information in environment variables.  You can do this with `cf set-env appname env value`.

Additionally you could create a user provided service to store your credentials as well. You can do this with `cf create-user-provided-service`.

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html